# What causes [ERROR] WSREP: could not parse UUID from '' in a Galera node while recovering

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, galera

There is a Galera cluster running on docker containers which are managed by kubernetes with 3 nodes from last 1 week but all of a sudden galera-0 node goes down and it's not able to bring it up back.

The main reason which I can understand is due to the following reason from the logs:

`[ERROR] WSREP: could not parse UUID from ''`

`2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1`

What I can see from the logs that the group state doesn't match the local state

```
Group state: 3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc:41060224
Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
```

And finally it says:

`2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc): 1 (Operation not permitted)
         at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.`

Complete logs from the crashing node of galera:

```
root@ip-172-31-26-54:/home/ubuntu/zm-load-testing# kubectl logs -f zmc-galera-0
iam=zmc-galera-0
all_hosts=zmc-galera-0.zmc-galera
zmc-galera-1.zmc-galera
zmc-galera-2.zmc-galera
zmc-galera-0 - Creating /root/.my.cnf...
zmc-galera-0 - /etc/mysql/conf.d/zmc-galera.cnf:
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=30
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0.001
query_cache_size=0
#value should be further increased for bulky hosts
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
table_open_cache=2000
# Value is: 200 + max_connections + 2 * table_open_cache
innodb_open_files=6200
max_connections=2000
user=mysql

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_log_conflicts=ON
# BitMask on when to enforces strict cluster-wide causality checks
wsrep_sync_wait=15
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=300M; gcache.page_size=300M"
# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name=zmc-galera
# Value is: 4 * number of dedicated cores
wsrep_slave_threads=16
wsrep_node_name=zmc-galera-0
# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'zmc-galera-1.zmc-galera' (-2)
cluster state=CLUSTER_RUNNING
zmc-galera-0 - Rejoining a running cluster...
zmc-galera-0 - Checking cluster state file for valid seqno...
zmc-galera-0 - Need to recover seqno from database
zmc-galera-0 - This is the seqno recovered from the database: -1.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    75  100    63  100    12  10500   2000 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12500
cluster addr from svc-coordinator: 10.244.2.112,10.244.5.165,10.244.1.96,10.244.2.125,10.244.2.134
zmc-galera-0 - Creating init file /var/lib/mysql/.initialized...
zmc-galera-0 - Starting the database...
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.35-MariaDB-1~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 25.3.23(r3789) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [ERROR] WSREP: could not parse UUID from ''
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, safe_to_bootstrap: 0
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 10.244.2.134; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 300M; gcache.recover = no; gcache.size = 300M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.i
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc:0 -> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk successfully
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'zmc-galera', peer '10.244.2.112:,10.244.5.165:,10.244.1.96:,10.244.2.125:,10.244.2.134:'
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to da31cd92 tcp://10.244.2.134:4567
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Warning] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://10.244.2.134:4567' points to own listening address, blacklisting
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to 9fd5389f tcp://10.244.5.165:4567
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers:
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to 6e5593b7 tcp://10.244.1.96:4567
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: declaring 6e5593b7 at tcp://10.244.1.96:4567 stable
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: declaring 9fd5389f at tcp://10.244.5.165:4567 stable
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Node 6e5593b7 state prim
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,6e5593b7,243) memb {
        6e5593b7,0
        9fd5389f,0
        da31cd92,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr without UUID: tcp://10.244.2.112:4567
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr proto entry 0x7fce8204cf00
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr without UUID: tcp://10.244.2.125:4567
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr proto entry 0x7fce8204d040
2019-08-29  7:19:51 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: clear restored view
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'zmc-galera'
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983666688 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 2, memb_num = 3
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 6473ce8b-ca2d-11e9-a3c1-ae9c9b27f45d
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 6473ce8b-ca2d-11e9-a3c1-ae9c9b27f45d from 0 (zmc-galera-1)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 6473ce8b-ca2d-11e9-a3c1-ae9c9b27f45d from 1 (zmc-galera-2)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 6473ce8b-ca2d-11e9-a3c1-ae9c9b27f45d from 2 (zmc-galera-0)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 4,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 232,
        members    = 2/3 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 41060224,
        last_appl. = -1,
        protocols  = 0/8/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = 3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [28, 28]
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 41060224)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
        Group state: 3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc:41060224
        Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc:41060224, view# 233: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 2, protocol version 3
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524476430080 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '10.244.2.134' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '1'  '' '
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: rsync|10.244.2.134:4444/rsync_sst
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 8 (3, 2)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 41060224, protocol version: 3
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524571707136 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc): 1 (Operation not permitted)
         at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: Member 2.0 (zmc-galera-0) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (zmc-galera-1)(SYNCED) as donor.
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524505790208 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 41060224)
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
2019-08-29  7:19:52 140524983352064 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0 -> 3cc86b15-b805-11e9-a7e5-f687881917cc:41060224
2019-08-29  7:19:55 140524522567424 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer da31cd92 with addr tcp://10.244.2.134:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S
2019-08-29  7:19:55 140524522567424 [Note] WSREP: (da31cd92, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured this out already, but I had the same issue with xtrabackup-v2 for the sst_method and that required validating the master node had the proper sst_auth user created and the firewall ports 3306, 4444, 4567 and 4568 are open.

Also in your case, it seems it doesn't see your mysql server so maybe there's something (i.e. firewall ports) not allowing the connection?

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'zmc-galera-1.zmc-galera' (-2)
cluster state=CLUSTER_RUNNING
```